# Jmeter response header value processing

Tags: header, response, jmeter

I have REST webservice call via Jmeter. After placing the request, I am getting the response back with response headers.

To view the response headers value I am using View Results Tree listener.
I am able to see the needed parameter under the SamplerResult tab of View Results Tree.
That parameter is an integer value.

My question is : how to take the average value of that parameter from the View Results Tree section for all the requests(5000 requests) that I have submitted

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want:

- Declare a User Defined Variable (nbIterations)
- Use a [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) (check Headers, call it time)
- Use a [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) (add Groovy to jmeter/lib/ext/) which will do something like this:

  ```
  Long time = (Long) vars.get("time");
  Long sum = (Long) vars.get("sum");
  if(sum == null) {
      sum = new Long(0);
  }
  sum = new Long(sum.longValue()+time.longValue);
  vars.put("sum", sum);
  ```
- Finally you have it through {__BeanShell(${sum}/${nbIterations})}